# How to relocate global packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

In the process of getting familiar with npm, ive installed a bunch of stuff globally, including angular cli - into my users directory on windows (C:\users...)

How can I either relocate this directory or uninstall and reinstall to a different folder?

Comment: Just use NPM to remove it from where it is now and then reinstall it where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it one by one by

```
npm uninstall angular-cli

npm -g install angular-cli
```

without `-g` will interact with current directory package.json while with `-g` do it globally (your %USER_PROFILE%)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change directories like that. Global installation chooses the path to `{prefix}/lib/node_modules` by default as the program refers to this path when looking for `-g` modules. You can't change them.

For local installation files automatically go to `./node_modules/.bin/` and program checks from there.

Please see https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/